# Image does not load in report c#

Tags: c#, image, report

Hello I have report in c# software, but it doesn't load image from database, how can i solve this error?

[IMAGE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAz9k.png)

CODE LOAD DATA IS:

```
String Query = "SELECT Utente.LogoAzienda,Preventivo.DataInserimento,Preventivo.RiferimentoInterno,Preventivo.Testata,Preventivo.Chiusura,Cliente.Titolo,Cliente.RagioneSociale,Cliente.Indirizzo,Cliente.Cap,Cliente.Citta,Cliente.Provincia  FROM Preventivo  inner join Cliente  on Cliente.IdCliente = Preventivo.IdCliente  inner join Utente  on Preventivo.UtenteCreazione = Utente.Username";

        SqlConnection conn = db.apriconnessione();

        DataStampaPreventivoCompleto d = new DataStampaPreventivoCompleto();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
        da.Fill(d, d.Tables[0].TableName);

        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",d.Tables[0]);
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        this.reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();

        db.chiudiconnessione();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Would you bring your code here

Comment: In your database do you have only bmp images?, there might be issue with MIME type you have set image/bmp, try with image/png, image/gif, image/jpg

Comment: the image is in format bmp